# fit many logistic regressions simultaneously, how?

Tags: r, statistics, regression, data-science

In `R`, the `lm` function allows you to fit multiple, separate linear models simultaneously - from the [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/lm.html) for `lm`:

> If response is a matrix a linear model is fitted separately by
>   least-squares to each column of the matrix.

But how can you fit multiple separate models simultaneously for a GLM, e.g. for logistic regression?

`glm.fit` requires the response `y` to be a vector.  If you give it a matrix in the `y` argument, then it just uses the first column of the `y` matrix and builds a single GLM model.

Comment: You'll need to just create a loop or use some sort of map/apply function. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Perhaps you are overemphasizing the "simultaneously" part. When `y` is a matrix, `lm` doesn't estimate those separate models as a single, related system; that's just a shortcut ("*fitted separately*"). Clearly `glm` doesn't have this shortcut. Then if you want to implement one, that's fine (after following MrFlick's suggestions).

Comment: Actually, it does look `lm.fit()` might [do all of the fits simultaneously](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/stats/R/lm.R#L105-L117); it calls `dqrls` ([here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/appl/dqrls.f)), which can solve the whole linear system simultaneously.  But I agree that this isn't feasible (or at least not easy) for GLMs.

Comment: Can you clarify why you want to do this (computational efficiency or convenience or ... ?)

Comment: i need to fit several thousand logistic regressions. looping can get slow

Comment: so, yes, for computational efficiency